# How can I call a method parameter from jar in java program without cmd

Tags: java, spring, jar

How can I call a method parameter from `jar` in a java program  without `cmd`?

Comment: Can you add more details to your questions? Have written any code at all? People at StackOverflow cannot help you unless you tell them where you're getting stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear: 
what is your mean of calling a parameter. calling is for methods not parameters
what is your mean of cmd

if you want to use a method or class or function from a jar file just add the jar file to your project 
import the needed classes from it and use them in your program

How to add jar to project depends on IDE that you use for example in eclipse:

https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

http://www.java67.com/2017/04/how-to-add-jar-file-in-eclipse-project.html

---

Add your jar to your project

in your main class (one that has main method) import the needed class from your jar:

```
import the.package.of.your.jar.library.className

public static void main(String[] args){
    // here use your imported class
}
```

you need to know the package of jar the classes and how to use them. you should study descriptions of the developer of the jar for this. this depends on the jar library which you imported

Comment: cmd is command line , jar added then how to call a method from jar.

Comment: open your main class which has " public static void main(String[] args) "  then import the class from jar that you want to this class and use the imported class in your main function

Comment: give a example links and will try it.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)